# Does collections in CQL3 have certain limits?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

As there are two ways to support wide rows in CQL3..One is to use composite keys and another is to use collections like Map, List and Set. The composite keys method can have millions of columns (transposed to rows).. This is solving some of our use cases.

However, if we use collections, I want to know if there is a limit that the collections can store a certain number/amount of data (Like earlier with Thrift C* supports up-to 2 billion columns in a row)

Comment: where is the documentation on the using composite keys as we need the millions of columns in one use case we have?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apart from the performance issue, there is a protocol issue which limits the number of items you can access to 65536.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201305.mbox/%3CCAENxBwx6pcSA=cWn=dKW_52K5odw5F3Xigj-zn_4BwFth+4ruA@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of that limitation from the protocol limiting the size to 65536. Thanks for the info

Comment: [CASSANDRA-5428](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5428) raised this limit to 2B (2^31) in Cassandra 2.1 when a client connects using native protocol **v3**.

Answer (score 20):

It is strongly recommended to store only a limited amount of data in collections & maps.

The reasons:

1. Collections and maps are fetched as a whole, entirely. You can not
   "slice" on collections so putting lots of data in collections/maps
   will have impact on perf when reading them
2. The CQL3 implementation of Lists is not performant for
   insertion/removal in the middle of the list. For append/prepend
   operations, it's quite fast. For insertion/removal element at index
   i, it will require a read-before-write. Basically, part of the list
   will be re-written because they need to be shifted to the good index
3. Insertion/removal for Set and Map are more performant since they use
   the column key for storage/sorting/indexing

Now to answer to your question, is there a hard limit on the number of elements in a collection/map, the answer is <s>no, technically there is no limit other than the classical 2 billions limit that already exist in Thrift</s> yes, it is limited to 65536 as  mentioned above by GlynD.

The related JIRA [CASSANDRA-5428](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5428)

Comment: CASSANDRA-5428 was resolved in Cassandra >= 2.1 when a client connects with native protocol **v3**. Under those conditions, your original statement is correct as the protocol uses the same size limit as the underlying storage layer (# cells / partition <= 2^31).

Answer (score 6):

The revised *non-frozen* [collection-related limits](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-cql/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html), after [CASSANDRA-5428](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5428) was resolved in version 2.1 and when using **version 3** or later of the native protocol, are:

```
======+==========+================+================
 TYPE | SIZE     | # KEYS         | VALUE SIZE
======+==========+================+================
 List | 2B (231)  | n/a             | 65,535 (216-1)  
 Set  | 2B (231)  | n/a             | 65,535 (216-1)  
 Map  | 2B (231)  | 65,535 (216-1)  | 65,535 (216-1)  
======+==========+================+================
```

Clients connecting via Thrift and earlier versions of the C* native protocol are still limited by those respective transports.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the limitation of 64k items in a collection, from http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html:

These are the *TWO* limitations:

> Maximum size of an item is limited to 64k (max value of an unsinged short)
>
> Number of items in collections are limited to 64K (max value of an unsinged short)

Answer (score 0):

Also collections are serialized so this adds an overhead. See CASSANDRA-5428 as well.