# Should I create a new column for a field I need to read often? Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra database with id and jsonData fields.I am often fetching the value of this particular field in the jsonData.

Is it better if I create a new column for that field in the database in terms of time performance? If so, what's the difference between the two methods?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your structure is

```
CREATE TABLE abc.test ( id UUID PRIMARY KEY,  json map<int,text> );
```

You have a field called *new_column* in the json which is getting called again and again and you want to change it to

```
CREATE TABLE abc.test ( id UUID PRIMARY KEY, new_column int, json map<int,text> );
```

There are both advantages and disadvantages to the approach.

Advantage:

- There are a lot of limitations with collections which you can avoid
  by using columns directly. Some of them are answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573507/does-collections-in-cql3-have-certain-limits/18574805#18574805).
- I am assuming you will not need all the data every time on the map which is inefficient as Cassandra will retrieve the collection as a whole, so you will get all the data even if not needed.
- You can also use *new_column* as clustering key so you can add filters on it,
  not sure if it is required in your case or not. You can always not specify the *new_column* and retrieve all data for the *id*.
- Clearly defined schema which makes it easier to understand the system.

Disadvantage:

1. May be you will have *new_column*  as a sparse column But that should
   be fine as most of the Big Data system were created to handle this
   sparse data map problem.
2. Data migration.

I will highly recommend adding *new_column* as a separate column.